# Dynamically resolvable Twig namespaces

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a Symfony application that handles request from multiple domains. On these domains, customers have the ability to create custom Twig templates that can be used in their CMS module. These templates are saved to a `/path/to/ftp/example.com/cms_templates/` directory.

In previous versions of Symfony, rendering these templates was not an issue. On an incoming request on mydomain.com/page_one, the absolute path of the Twig template could be resolved to e.g. `/path/to/ftp/mydomain.com/cms_templates/page_one.html.twig`. The existence of the template was verified and the template was rendered. However, in Symfony 4 support for absolute template paths [has been removed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-4.0.md#frameworkbundle).

I thought of [registering an extra Twig namespace](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html#registering-your-own-namespaces) in `twig.paths` called 'custom' that points to `/path/to/ftp` and then reference the templates with `@custom/mydomain.com/cms_templates/page_one.html.twig`. The problem is, `/path/to/ftp` contains not only templates but loads and loads of other files too. And the TemplateCacheWarmer is looping through all of these files.

What I'am actually looking for is a way to register a Twig namespace, say `@cms` that is resolved on the fly such that I can inject the hostname of the current request in it. I would then be able to reference a template using `@cms\page_one.html.twig`. Cache warmup isn't necessary for these templates.

How to achieve such functionality? I looked ad the Twig documentation but it looks like I just can't figure it out.

**TLDR;** How to get Symfony/Twig to resolve the template `@foo\template.html.twig` to `/path/to/domain.com/templates/template.html.twig` when *domain.com* differs between requests.

Comment: Hello! I am quite interested in your solution. Did you found one?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to [prepend configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html)

```
   public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $bundles = $container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');

        if (isset($bundles['TwigBundle'])) {

            $config = $container->getExtensionConfig('twig')[0];
            $paths = ['/path/to/cms' => 'cms'];

            if (array_key_exists('path', $config)) {
                $paths = array_merge($config['paths'], $paths);
            }

            $config['paths'] = $paths;

            $container->prependExtensionConfig('twig', $config);
        }
    }
```

The problem would be this:

[image: more then one bundle]

If you are building some kind of CMS - then this would mean - no other bundle/module/plugin could ever register additional twig namespaces again - if I am right.

So... I am interested in other solutions if there are some.